# add value to multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I want to update my dataframe adding value in various columns.

My dataframe has  A-Z columns name. 
I created a list specifiying which column want to update.

```
upd<-c("a","b","c","d")
```

And i used simple R syntax to update

```
df<-df[,names(df)%in%upd]+5
```

But I only have a,b,c,d columns.

is there one way to save all columns?.

thanks

Comment: Try `df[,names(df) %in% upd] <- df[,names(df) %in% upd] + 5`

Comment: @markus thanks mate it works! is this way efficient?

Comment: That is pretty straight forward, no?

Comment: @markus yes thanks!

Comment: `ind <- names(df) %in% upd; df[ind] <-df[ind]+5` might be a bit faster but it probably won't matter

Comment: or for readability, but slower : `library(dplyr); df <- mutate_at(df, upd, ~.+5) `